# how to highlite word which is click in Textview android

Tags: android, textview

I am creating one application in which I get input from user in EditText.

Now after click on button the inputed string is display in TextView. Now my question is when user click on any single word I make that word as highlighted in TextView.

For Example : User input : Hello friend how are you.

When user click "Hello" it will be highlighted in TextView. Or when user click on "how" it will be highlighted.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView _tv;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
_tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv );

SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello friend how are you.");

ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 0,5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 6, 12, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 13, 16, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 17, 20, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 21, 24, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

_tv.setText(ss);
_tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{ //clickable span
public void onClick(View textView) {
//do something

   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
   ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);//set text color 
   ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
} 
}
}
```

Edit:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Click" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

You can split the string by space and set each word as a spannable string. Then make the spannable string clickable. This way you need not hard code the lengths of the String. user can click on any word in textview and its highlighted.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView _tv;
String[] each;
SpannableString ss1;
Button b;
EditText et;
    String s;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
_tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv );

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        s=et.getText().toString();
        _tv.setText("");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            each = s.split("\\s+");
        }
        for(int i=0;i<each.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("................"+each[i]);
            ss1=  new SpannableString(each[i]);
            ss1.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 0, ss1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            _tv.append(ss1); 
            _tv.append(" "); 

        }
        _tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

   });
}
class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{ //clickable span
public void onClick(View textView) {
//do something

   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 @Override
 public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
   ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);//set text color 
   ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
 }
 }
 }
```

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring.
For styling spannable string.

Resulting snap shot.

[image]

Comment: User can click on any word, word is not fix.

Comment: Hello.... when user write string it not added to _txt when he press OK button. stuck with it plz help.

Comment: i could not understand your comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26662/discussion-between-hardik-and-raghunandan)

Comment: Hello. I done which click of textview.. but how can user know which word is click ?? is it possible to display ?